# JQuery Sortable sort 2 different lists synchronized

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have two "lists" to sort.
**First:**

```
<div id="keys">
   <span id="key1">Foo1</span>
   <span id="key2">Foo2</span>
   <span id="key3">Foo3</span>
   <span id="key4">Foo4</span>
</div>
```

**Second**

```
<div id="vals">
   <span id="val1">Bar1</span>
   <span id="val2">Bar2</span>
   <span id="val3">Bar3</span>
   <span id="val4">Bar4</span>
</div>
```

My JQuery is following:

```
$(function() {
    $('#keys').sortable({
        placeholder: "ui-state-highlight"
    });
});
```

The JQuery just makes the first list sortable. Now I need the second list to synchronize with the first. So if I drag "key2" to the last spot, "val2" should be at the last spot too.
The Second list shall not be sortable.
I found [this](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/q6bbF/1/) which is basically what I need, but the amount of keys and vals vary and I do not know how to loop the code from the example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To preserve syncronization between the two lists you need to handle the update event as reported in the following snippet:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#keys').sortable({
    placeholder: "ui-state-highlight",
    update: function( event, ui ){
      var nextPosition;
      var index = ui.item.attr('id').replace('key', '');
      currPosition = $('#val' + index);
      if (ui.item.next().attr('id') === undefined) {
        nextPosition = $('#vals span:last');
        currPosition.insertAfter(nextPosition);
      } else {
        index = ui.item.next().attr('id').replace('key', '');
        nextPosition = $('#val' + index);
        currPosition.insertBefore(nextPosition);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<div id="keys">
    <span id="key1">Foo1</span>
    <span id="key2">Foo2</span>
    <span id="key3">Foo3</span>
    <span id="key4">Foo4</span>
</div>
<div id="vals">
    <span id="val1">Bar1</span>
    <span id="val2">Bar2</span>
    <span id="val3">Bar3</span>
    <span id="val4">Bar4</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! This works just perfect and as I wanted it to work. You definitely made my day ! :)